# How to ignore distance when rendering a GeoSpatial anchor with ARCore

Tags: arcore

I have followed this tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/geospatial/codelab) for creating an android app that shows geospatial anchors using arcore. I completed that successfully. But when I try tapping a location farther away, the resulting image on the screen is smaller (or bigger) depending on the device's distance from the LatLng (which makes sense). But how do I ignore the distance unit? I just want the anchor/image to appear in the direction of the LatLng regardless of the distance.

A similar example of the result I am looking for is Google Map's Live View on Android.

Comment: Hey! Did you found the solution for this. I am facing the same issue when I take lat long longer than 200m anchor is not visible on screen . Any workAround?

Comment: Kinda. What I ended up doing was projecting the location (using trig) to a set distance way from the device. That way all anchors were "the same" distance away, so they all appeared the same size. It worked but the app as a whole didnt feel super smooth so I abandoned it.